# Adding one ui file into another

Tags: c++, qt

Suppose i have designer files with there respective classes say `form.ui` , `form.h` , `form.cpp` and `myclass.ui` , `myclass.h` , `myclass,cpp` . Now what i want is 2 different things .
Now i have a widget and a layout in the `myclass.ui` file and i now using `addLayout` function i add the `form.ui` file into it . Now i want it so that whole of the `form.ui` file content should come into small layout space by self adjusting . But that is not happening . So how could i achieve that

Answer (score 1):

QUILoader is your solution but maybe not the best, specially if you have custom actions & functions for your form.ui in your form.h & form.cpp. The easiest way its to [promote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yt-YCxgEnyw) a widget inside your widget and then make it not visible. When you have to show it, you can just change the hidden state.

In another case, you can create it dynamically and manage the memory by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Example of [`QUiLoader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/quiloader.html):

```
// your main widget
MyClass *myclass = new MyClass();

// to generate a widget with a .ui file
QUiLoader loader;
QFile file("form.ui");
file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QWidget *myForm = loader.load(&file, this);
file.close();

// insert the widget in your main container
myclass->layout()->addWidget(myForm);
```